# Empty resolv.conf?

Tags: networking, pi-3, wifi, wireless

I just got my raspberry pi 3, and everything's working great, except for the wifi. I'm trying to follow another step by step instructions on a different website, and I noticed that in my

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

It is literally empty except for

```
# Generated by resolvconf
```

I am wondering how to fix this and make it not empty (I assume it shouldn't be empty)

I am using:

```
Linux raspberry Pi 4.4.34-v7+
```

It has onboard wifi, I am not using an adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume it shouldn't be empty

Not if you want DNS resolution to take place; this is what's required for the system to look up IP addresses based on hostname.  You can check quickly by comparing:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

To:

```
ping google.com
```

The latter doesn't actually resolve to the former, but in any case, if the first one succeeds and the second one doesn't, you don't have DNS, which will make using the internet very awkward.

**However, that it's empty if you are not online yet is normal.**  It should get filled in automagically when you connect to a router (wifi or otherwise) via DHCP.

If you aren't using DHCP (because you are using a static IP or some such), you can in a pinch add:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

To `/etc/resolv.conf`.  Those are public Google owned DNS servers, which are [reliable and reasonably quick](https://www.dnsperf.com/).

Comment: I would argue that using Google Public DNS is almost always an improvement on DNS supplied by your ISP. In my experience, it is common for ISPs to overcache DNS records and not honor TTLs to reduce the overhead of their DNS servers; but means that you are almost always getting out of date records.

Comment: @JeremyDavis Good point, edited to reflect that.